# Blogger JSON Feed API more than 500 posts

Tags: javascript, json, api, blogger

I use Blogger JSON Feed API get to get time published of the all post [json.feed.entry[i].published.$t], but my blog has than 500 post and API get only 500 post?

I have searched on the internet know that is the limit of Feed API.

```
http://blog.vnlives.net/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999
```

And if use API old post then use other JSON Feed API other.

```
http://blog.vnlives.net/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999&start-index=501
```

How to get time published all post in my blog? Please help to me. (sorry my english is not good.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is call all feed api, the first I'm call default like:

```
<script src="http://blog.vnlives.net/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=recentposts&max-results=99999" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And save all the information need into a variable. After the feed api action finish, I'm add feed api old post like:

```
document.write('<script src="http://blog.vnlives.net/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=recentposts&max-results=99999&start-index=501" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

And my json callback will call again with feed api old post.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google JavaScript Client Library - Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts#resource-representations) to retrieve all posts of a blog.

**See the following example:**

```
  <script>
  function renderResults(response) {
    if (response.items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        //do whatever you want with the posts of your blog
      }      
    }
    if(response.nextPageToken) {
      var blogId = 'XXX Your blogId XXX';
      var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
        'blogId': blogId,
        'pageToken': response.nextPageToken,
        'maxResults': 100,
      });
      request.execute(renderResults);
    }
  }
  function init() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('XXX Get your API Key from https://code.google.com/apis/console XXX');
    gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v3', function() {
        var blogId = 'XXX Your blogId XXX';
        var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
          'blogId': blogId,
          'maxResults': 100,
        });
        request.execute(renderResults);        
    });
  }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think blogger only allow to serve max 500 per request, so it's not possible to serve more than 500.

CMIIW

Comment: Completely out of topic